# Как будет правильно прописать слово: в написаном?

Tags: грамматика

Доброго времени суток!
 Хотел выяснить, как правильно написать слово: решил не чего не менять ***в написаном*** 
 Как будет правильно прописать слово: в написаном? Так как по запросу в интернете выдаёт это слово, как без ошибки. И именно поэтому, хотелось бы узнать уже наверняка, что мне просто нужно, только  обучить свой компьютер.

Comment: Гугл сразу предлагает правильный вариант (с двумя -нн-).

Comment: Что именно вам тут надо уточнить?

Answer (score 3):

И Вам — доброго!

А давайте и всё другое «пропишем» по словарю и учебникам? Самоё мысль оставляю как есть — как Вам бог на душу положил...

*Хотел выяснить, как правильно написать слово: решил **НИЧЕГО** не менять в **написаННом**. Как будет правильно **НАПИСАТЬ** слово: в **написаННом**? Так как по запросу в **И**нтернете выдаёт это слово как без ошибки. И именно поэтому хотелось бы узнать уже наверняка, что мне просто нужно только обучить свой компьютер*.

У страдательного причастия *написанный* есть приставка; этого пока достаточно для удвоения *Н* в суффиксе.

Для проверки слова в данном случае годится [любой орфографический словарь](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) — всегда в единственном числе и в мужском роде (если это не ножницы и не кенгуру).

Для более основательного проникновения в тему читаем "[Причастия и отглагольные прилагательные: отличия и правила написания](http://writercenter.ru/blog/grammar/prichastija-i-otglagolnye-prilagatelnye-otlichija-i-pravila-napisanija.html)".

Comment: 1. "в **и**нтернете", хотя на эту тему можно флеймить бесконечно. 2 "**потому** что мне нужно..." если мы пишем на русском русском языке, а не россиянском

Answer (score 3):

***"Решил ничего не менять в написанном"***. Здесь "написанное" - это **существительное** (переход  из причастия).

**Схема образования:** **на**писать (глагол совершенного вида) - написа**нн**ый (причастие) - написа**нн**ое (сущ. ср.р.).

В причастии "написанный" пишется две буквы НН (образовано от приставочного глагола совершенного вида), две буквы НН сохраняются в существительном "написанное".

**Для сравнения**: одна буква Н пишется в отглагольных прилагательных, образованных от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида: красить - краше**н**ый (прилаг.), но: **по**красить - **по**краше**нн**ый (прич.)

Comment: Миль пардон, я все понимаю, по подпись Vera и "решил" в прямой речи - это немного шокинг. Сам завернуть первое предложение в обрамление хоть какое не могу (по размеру правки)